# Powershell script to Copy and Replace web.config

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-2.0, tfsbuild, powershell-3.0

I want a powershell script to copy the file from source to intermediate folder and then from intermediate folder to destination folder. In the destination folder there will already be a config file. So want to replace the web.config file in destination folder.

This is what I tried:

First attempt:

```
$src = "C:\Websites\CTABS\CTABSEQA2014\Web.config" 
$dst = "C:\2014_VCI_TEMP\" 

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "txt.*.test.*" -Recurse | % { 
    #Creates an empty file at the destination to make sure that subfolders exists 
    New-Item -Path $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -ItemType File -Force 
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -Force 
}
```

Second attempt:

```
$src = "C:\2014_VCI_TEMP\Web.config" 
$dst = "C:\Websites\CTABS\CTABSEQA2014\"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "txt.*.test.*" -Recurse | % { 
    #Creates an empty file at the destination to make sure that subfolders exists 
    New-Item -Path $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -ItemType File -Force 
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($src,$dst) -Force 
}
```

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you have pasted your code and said "this code doesn't work", but you haven't explained what is wrong with it and what needs to be fixed. Your code doesn't seem to do anything with an intermediate folder. Why do you use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` if you already know the source file and its location? `Copy-Item  -LiteralPath $src -Destination $dst -Force` seems like it would do what you ask.. ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am sorry for the formatting. First part of the code was copying the file from source to intermediate folder and second part of the code was copying and replacing the file in destination folder. I am new to powershell. Can you please tell me the way how should I carry out this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a file to check if the folder exists, just use Test-Path:

```
$src = "C:\2014_VCI_TEMP\Web.config" 
$dst = "C:\Websites\CTABS\CTABSEQA2014\\"

if((Test-Path $dst) -and (Test-Path $src))
{
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $src -Destination $dst -Force
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Folder or file does not exist"
}
```

This will check the path and the file first, if they exist, it will copy the file.

Comment: Will this script copy the file from source folder and replace the existing file in the destination folder? And why do you have 2 '\\' after the CTABSEQA2014?

Comment: yes, it will copy the source file to the destination folder overwriting it if needed. The extra \\ on $dst is just to retain the formatting in StackOverflow as it escapes the closing " It will run in PowerShell with or without the extra \